# Как короче всего ввести и вывести одно число?

Tags: haskell

Как короче всего ввести 1 число, разделить его на 2 и вывести?

Решаю код-гольф на одной платформе. Я придумал следующий вариант:

```hs
main=interact$(/2).read
```

Но на платформе есть решение короче (код не показывается).

Comment: Ваш код не пройдет проверку типов, потому, что не преобразовывает число обратно в строку.

Answer (score 1):

Вот кратчайшее решение, кому интересно:

```hs
main=readLn>>=print.(/2)
```

Comment: Не нужно плодить аккаунты, если это самоответ.